# Loopback - Create a method to make it accessible in two different models

Tags: javascript, rest, loopback

I am using loopback. Create a new method called stats in a model called Report. That same method I want to create in another model called Acount but with a parameter that is the id.

Model Report:

```
Report.remoteMethod("stats", {
        accepts: [],
        returns: { arg: "features", type: "Object" },
        http: { verb: "get", path: "/stats" }
    });
```

How can i solve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use "accepts" to define the path parameter. and http path should be changed accordingly, "/stats/:id" or "/:id/stats"

```
Account.stats = function(id, cb) {
    cb(null, 'ID ' + id);
};

Account.remoteMethod("stats", {
      accepts: [
    { arg: "id", type: "number", http: { source: "path" } }
    ],
      returns: { arg: "features", type: "Object" },
        http: { verb: "get", path: "/stats/:id" }
    });
```

Comment: In the Model Report I have the stats method. In the Model Account what you told me. I run http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/Accounts/390/stats and I get this: {"features": "ID 390"}

I hope I get the same result as reports / stats but with the id parameter filter

Comment: @josego I just gave an example, I don't actually know the real scenario you are expecting from. You got

 `{"features": "ID 390"}`

because in the Account.stats method, the call back is returning 

`cb(null, 'ID ' + id);`